# Unable to View Printable version of Requisition (First operand of . is NULL)

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

In Peoplesoft FSCM 9.2 in the Worklist (Main Menu --> Worklist --> Worklist) there is a link called "View printable version". when this is clicked on, the below error message is displayed. I am still fairly new to developing in Peoplesoft so I'm not sure where to go with this issue. So far I have turned on the PeopleCode Trace and reviewed the trace file, I can see where the error is generated but still not sure what the actual problem is. Hoping someone can help, thanks!

**Error:**

[image]

**PeopleCode Trace File log:**

```
PSAPPSRV.6204 (4027)     1-273    07.40.55    0.000000              109:       
If All(&transdescr) Then
PSAPPSRV.6204 (4027)     1-274    07.40.55    0.000000              112:       
&reqLineREC.QTY_REQ_C.Value = 
&oDecimalCntl.QtyPrecision(&reqLineREC.QTY_REQ.Value);
PSAPPSRV.6204 (4027)     1-275    07.40.55    0.000000                       
Fetch Field: REQ_LINE_EXT.QTY_REQ Value=3
PSAPPSRV.6204 (4027)     1-276    07.40.55    0.000000 ErrorReturn-> 236 - 
First operand of . is NULL, so cannot access member QtyPrecision. (180,236) 
PV_REQ_PRINT.ReqPrint.OnExecute  Name:getLines  PCPC:8195  Statement:112 
Called from:PV_REQ_PRINT.ReqPrint.OnExecute  Name:writeFile  Statement:393 
Called from:PV_REQ_APPROVAL.GBL.PV_MAINNAV_HTML.PV_PRINT_REQ.FieldChange  
Statement:14
PSAPPSRV.6204 (4027)     1-277    07.40.55    0.001000   <<< end-ext   
Nest=02 writeFile PV_REQ_PRINT.ReqPrint.OnExecute Dur=0.056085 CPU=0.015625 
Cycles=600
PSAPPSRV.6204 (4027)     1-278    07.40.55    0.000000   <<< end       
Nest=01  PV_REQ_APPROVAL.GBL.PV_MAINNAV_HTML.PV_PRINT_REQ.FieldChange 
Dur=0.056931 CPU=0.015625 Cycles=680
```

Comment: Looks like the error message is saying that `&oDecimalCntl` is null.  Look through the lines of the trace file above what you've posted, and try to figure out how '&oDecimalCntl` is getting assigned.  That should lead you to what data is causing `&oDecimalCntl` to either not get assigned or be assigned to NULL.